# Solutions of $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{2011}{S(n+i)}=S(n)^{2011}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $S(k)$ be the sum of digits of natural number $k$. Is there $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $$ \prod_{i=1}^{2011}{S(n+i)}=S(n)^{2011}?$$

All I could get is, since $2011=223\cdot9+4$ we have at least $222$ numbers on the LHS which are divisible by $9$, and $9|k\iff9|S(k)$, hence $9^{222}|S(n)^{2011}$, which means that $3|S(n)\iff3|n$. Is this even relevant for solution? Even more, is it even correct?

Comment: Also I have no idea how to tag this.

Comment: Its pretty easy to show each solution to this has $S(n)$ at least in the hundred millions... so if this is really a contest problem as pre-kidney believes the answer almost surely must be none exist.

Comment: The suggestion *Since this appears to be a contest problem from 2011, can you please post the attribution?* still applies.

Comment: It's from Serbian State Competition for High-school Students of Second Grade of Category A.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such $n$.
It's obvious that $S(n)> 1$.
We know that
$$(n,n+1)=1$$
and
$$S(n+1)=\begin{cases}S(n)+1&\text{last digit of $k$ is not 9}\\S(n)-9m+1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\tag{*}$$
if $\exists i, S(n+i)>S(n)$, let $m$ be the first index. Then by construction, $S(m−1)≤S(n)$. According to $(*)$, we have $S(m−1)=S(m)−1=S(n)$, which shows that $S(m)=S(n)+1$. since $(S(m),S(n))=1$, we have $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{2011}{S(n+i)}\neq S(n)^{2011}$ .
So $\forall i, S(n+i)\leq S(n)$, and particularly $S(n+1)<S(n)$. In this case $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{2011}{S(n+i)}< S(n)^{2011}$.
So, there is no such $n$.

Comment: Your statement, $\forall i, S(n+i)\leq S(n)$ does not follow logically from your preceding statements. Here's how to fill in that gap:
Begin by observing that $S(n+1)<S(n)$. Now consider the sequence $S(n+1),S(n+2),\cdots,S(n+2011)$. At each step, we either increase by $1$, or we decrease. Let $m$ be the first index $n+i$ such that $S(m)> S(n)$. Then by construction, $S(m-1)\leq S(n)$. So $S(m-1)=S(m)-1 = S(n)$, which shows that $S(m)=S(n)+1$, contradiction.

Comment: @pre-kidney thanks for your comment... my fault to skip these steps ;-)